# ReactNative FlatList Large Data Rendering Problem (renders too many times)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to implement load more (paginated) data on flat list scrolling (onReachEnd).
but flat list renders item too many times when I concat new data with previous data (this.state.data)
Let's see what's happening:

Here is my PureComponent class:

```
class SampleComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return(
            <View key={this.props.id} style={{padding: 8}}>
                <Text bold style={{fontSize: UI.fontSize.lg}}>{this.props.title}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm using this for each Item (row).

My App Component is like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    renderTimes;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            data: [],
        };
        this.renderTimes = 0;
    }

 componentDidMount() {
        this.fakeLoad();
    }


fakeLoad() {
        const start = this.state.data.length + 1;
        const data = [];
        for(let x = start; x <= start + 100; x++) {
            data.push({id: x.toString(), title: `Item #${x}`});
        }
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            data: prevState.data.concat(data)
        }));
    }

 render() {
     return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    extraData={this.state.data}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
                    renderItem={({item}) => {
                        this.renderTimes++;
                        console.log("render item " + item.id + " / " + this.renderTimes);
                        return (
                            <SampleComponent id={item.id} title={item.title}/>
                        );
                    }}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                    onEndReached={this.fakeLoad.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>
        );
}

}
```

fakeLoad method adds 100 data to current state.data
but in console.log I received this (just tail of logs) :

```
 LOG  render item 191 / 2503
 LOG  render item 192 / 2504
 LOG  render item 193 / 2505
 LOG  render item 194 / 2506
 LOG  render item 195 / 2507
 LOG  render item 196 / 2508
 LOG  render item 197 / 2509
 LOG  render item 198 / 2510
 LOG  render item 199 / 2511
 LOG  render item 200 / 2512
 LOG  render item 201 / 2513
 LOG  render item 202 / 2514
```

It means I scrolled to Item #202, and total render counter is showing 2514.
and of course I will see rendering items from #1 (first) over and over.

What should I do?

thanks for your help ...